PrimeFaces p:fileUpload icon not loading and I'm unable to change it
I'm migrating from PrimeFaces 6.0 to PrimeFaces 13.0.2.
Buttons generated with the <p:fileUpload /> tag have "pi pi-upload" as the default uploadIcon attribute. The problem I'm experiencing is that the icon is not displayed, and instead a square is displayed in its place. It looks like the icon hasn't loaded or wasn't found, as shown in this picture.
When I was using PrimeFaces 6.0 the icon displayed correctly.
I tried changing the uploadIcon attribute to any other icon, and I'm getting the same result. Icons work as intended when I put them in a <p:commandButton /> tag, so I suppose something is overriding the icon in the <p:fileUpload /> tag, but that's just my guess.
Here's my code (I changed sensitive information on the listener and update attributes):
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced"
              label="Seleccionar Archivo (*.xlsx)"
              auto="true"
              listener="#{managedBean.myMethod}"
              update="componentsToBeUploaded" />


Probably override in theme.css you should inspect it with something like Chrome developer tools. I know i was manualy replacing font awesome with PrimeIcons during one migration.

Not in fileUpload but datatable carets, but similar problem maybe

According to PF showcase which currently runs 13.0.4, the default icon is pi pi-plus: http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml Are you sure you're the right PF version and that you don't have overridden the default renderer for the PF upload component? (check any <renderer> entries in faces-config.xml)

Plus is to select file from directory, after selection PF renders 2 new buttons one of them to upload other to cancel selected file. Default behaviour wheb you just add <p;fileUpload />

See this ticket was fixed for PF13: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9299  It was fixed in 13.0.0   if you can create a reproducer using PrimeFaces Test project I can take a look but we use FileUpload and have no issues with icons.
